# How to save a program's running history to a file?

Tags: command-line, io-redirection

I'm running a program called `gatk-picard.sh` and it's printing out the running history/log (`INFO` rows below). Since the program will take about 20 hours to finisn and I wanted to put it on running when I am leaving my office but would check the running history in my home. How to save these history lines automatically after it's done?

What I have tried was `$gatk-picard.sh > log` but seems not working.

```
$ ./gatk-picard.sh 
INFO  16:08:50,858 HelpFormatter - -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
INFO  16:08:50,861 HelpFormatter - The Genome Analysis Toolkit (GATK) v3.6-0-g89b7209, Compiled 2016/06/01 22:27:29 
INFO  16:08:50,861 HelpFormatter - Copyright (c) 2010-2016 The Broad Institute 
INFO  16:08:50,862 HelpFormatter - For support and documentation go to https://www.broadinstitute.org/gatk 
INFO  16:08:50,862 HelpFormatter - [Fri Sep 16 16:08:50 EDT 2016] Executing on Linux 3.13.0-95-generic amd64 
INFO  16:08:50,862 HelpFormatter - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_102-b14 JdkDeflater
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably writing to `stderr` (file descriptor 2) instead of `stdout` (file descriptor 1, the default). `> filename` (which can also be written as `1> filename`) redirects `stdout` to a file. You can either redirect `stderr` to `stdout` first, like this:

```
gatk-picard.sh 2>&1 > log
```

or you can write `stderr` to its own file, like this:

```
./gatk-picard.sh 2>log_err >log_out
```